# Responsive text techniques

Tags: html, css, text, responsive

What's the best method for creative `responsive text` other than using `media queries`, I find that using `media queries` takes up too much time and I'm guessing there will be an alternative which will automatically resize it's self.

```css
h1 {
font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: You can use vh and vw units - resizes text based on the size  of the width or height of the viewport

Comment: I found that when using that method it's not the best for mobiles as the text becomes unreadable when the screen is that small.

Comment: Yeah I found that too so I set a rem for mobile and then if I need to resize based on viewport I add vw for tablet and above, you never get 100% reposive how you want it, unless you put in the time and do all the media queries

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'll take your advice on board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `vw`and `vh` units - resizes text based on the size of the width or height of the viewport

Respectively these are 1/100th of the width of the viewport, and 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

```css
h1 {
font-size: 22vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

[More information](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)